# How to compare coefficients from three different conditions? (using Python)

Tags: python, linear-regression, coefficients

I'm doing my research about comparing different three conditions(A, B, C) with regression. So I did an OLS Regression for each three conditions, and got coefficients.

And I want to compare these three coefficients(A, B, C) and figure out which IV was the best to influence DV.

So here's the questions.

**1. Can I just compare these three coefficients even if they are from different condition?**

**2. If question 1 is OK, how can I get significance (p-value) from coefficients that shows X(A or B or C) condition is the best? Is there any way to get it in python?** = Asking if there's a way to compare between coefficients.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question lacks lot of clarity. And may be should be asked first on [math stackexchange forum](https://math.stackexchange.com). For example, what is the input (we don't need application details. But, are they random variables? I mean I understood only that probability was involved only when you mentioned p-value. Linear Regression has other applications). Is the distribution of those input variables known? What do you mean by "compare"? (Sure, you can always compare things. The kind of comparison is what makes it pertinent or not).

Comment: What means "best"? (One could say that it is the one that has the higher p-value, that his the higher probability to observe the data given that it follows a model. But you seem to want to know that before computing p-value).

Comment: @chrslg 
- No, they are not random variables but score from the 7-point likert.

- The original data didn't follow normalized distribution, so I normalized data with MinMax Scaler.

- I meant 'compare' the three coefficients. For example, if C condition was the highest coefficient among the three, can I say that C was the most effective to DV?

Comment: @chrslg Linking 'the best' meaning with the comment above, 'compare' the coefficients and found the best among the three conditions (A, B, C)

Comment: The most similar problem with my question is here: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-compare-regression-coefficients-across-3-or-more-groups/